# ORA-00905: missing keyword errorerror

Tags: python, sql

I need help with an error I am getting with my SQL code. line 16 is the create table line
Error starting at line: 16 in command -

```
CREATE TABLE Order_Form (
    Order_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Order_ID PRIMARY KEY (Order_ID),
    Customer_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Customer_ID FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID),
    Order_Date DATE
);
```

Error report -

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
> 00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY` must `REFERENCES` another table.

Comment: i have tried and the primary key for the customer_id is on the other table but still gives an error :CREATE TABLE Order_Form (
    Order_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Order_ID PRIMARY KEY (Order_ID),
    Customer_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
--    REFERENCE Customer_ID FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Customer_ID) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID)
    Order_Date DATE );

Comment: Same error? Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64808670/edit) with your updated SQL attempt in post (then delete hard to read comment). As is, it looks incorrect syntax. Please read Oracle docs, tutorials, etc. on proper fk specification in `CREATE TABLE`. I think I see the comment symbol `--`. Also, post full error (not truncated as earlier one). Additionally, try moving all `CONSTRAINTS` to end of `CREATE TABLE`.